# Jupyter Notebook in Chrome

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to open Jupyter notebook in Chrome instead of Internet Explorer.Tried

Tried doing : jupyter notebook --generate-config in Anaconda prompt
Tried pasting this :'C:/path/to/your/chrome.exe %s'

## as  I am using windows 10

Error reads:c.NotebookApp.browser = '' to c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:/path/to/your/chrome.exe %s'

After this also, chrome not opening as default.

Comment: Can you clarify, did you actually specify the path to chrome.exe, or *literally* `'C:/path/to/your/chrome.exe %s'` (For example, on my machine it would be "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"

Comment: I know what I did wrong, But now I am clearly mentioning the path, still it will open in Internet Explore.(what I followed through my C drive and edit : 'C:\Program Files(x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe % s')

Comment: I'd expect you may need to put the path in double quotes, given that it has spaces in. And it looks like you've got a space after the % as well, which I suspect shouldn't be there.

Comment: Even after making these changes it's not happening. However,I found a little trick:search bar(Windows 10)> choose a default web browser > reset to default >Microsoft edge> changed to Chrome .Now Jupyter notebook is opening in Chrome. Thanks for trying to resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Set google chrome as your default browser and the work is done.